# Why does more randomness in the data generator result in better test set accuracy?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to come up with a Keras model that would do binary classification on image sequences. I split my dataset into train (1200 samples), valid (320 samples) and test (764 samples) partitions.

In the first step, I used [InceptionV3](https://keras.io/applications/#inceptionv3) to extract features from my dataset consisting of image sequences. I saved those sequences of extracted features to disk.

The next step is to feed those sequences as input data to my LSTM based model.

**Here is a minimal workable example that compiles:**

```py
import numpy as np
import copy
import random
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam

def get_sequence(sequence_no, sample_type):
    # Load sequence from disk according to 'sequence_no' and 'sample_type'
    # eg. 'sample_' + sample_type + '_' + sequence_no
    return np.zeros([100, 2048]) # added only for demo purposes, so it compiles

def frame_generator(batch_size, generator_type, labels):
    # Define list of sample indexes 
    sample_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(labels)):
        sample_list.append(i)
    # sample_list = [0, 1, 2, 3 ...]

    while 1:
        X, y = [], []
        # Generate batch_size samples
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            # Reset to be safe
            sequence = None

            # Get a random sample
            random_sample = random.choice(sample_list)

            # Get sequence from disk
            sequence = get_sequence(random_sample, generator_type)

            X.append(sequence)
            y.append(labels[random_sample])

        yield np.array(X), np.array(y)

# Data mimicking
train_samples_num = 1200
valid_samples_num = 320
labels_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(train_samples_num), dtype='uint8')
labels_valid = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(valid_samples_num), dtype='uint8')

batch_size = 32
train_generator = frame_generator(batch_size, 'train', labels_train)
val_generator = frame_generator(batch_size, 'valid', labels_valid)

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2048, input_shape=(100, 2048), dropout = 0.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Training
model.fit_generator(
    generator=train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=len(labels_train) // batch_size,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=len(labels_valid) // batch_size)
```

This example was compiled with:

```
python     3.6.8
keras      2.2.4
tensorflow 1.13.1
```

This works well, I ran 3 training sessions on this model (same setup, same train/valid/test partitioning) and the test accuracy mean was 96.9%.

**Then I started to ask myself whether it's a good idea to always choose a completely random sample from the sample list, inside the** `frame_generator()` **function, specifically line**
`random_sample = random.choice(sample_list)`. Picking samples completely at random makes it possible that some samples would be used way more than others, in the training session. Also, some of them would possibly never be used. **This made me think that the model would generalize less in this setup COMPARED TO if it would see the samples equally during training.**

**As a fix, changes applied to** `frame_generator()`:

Make a backup copy of the sample list, then remove a sample from the sample list every time after using it. When the sample list becomes empty, replace the sample list with its backup copy. Do this for the whole training session. This ensures that **ALL** of the samples are seen by the model at training with almost the **same frequency**.

This is the new version of `frame_generator()`. Marked with `#ADDED` the 4 lines added:

```py
def frame_generator(batch_size, generator_type, labels):
    # Define list of sample indexes 
    sample_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(labels)):
        sample_list.append(i)
    # sample_list = [0, 1, 2, 3 ...]
    sample_list_backup = copy.deepcopy(sample_list) # ADDED

    while 1:
        X, y = [], []
        # Generate batch_size samples
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            # Reset to be safe
            sequence = None

            # Get a random sample
            random_sample = random.choice(sample_list)
            sample_list.remove(random_sample) # ADDED
            if len(sample_list) == 0: # ADDED
                sample_list = copy.deepcopy(sample_list_backup) # ADDED

            # Get sequence from disk
            sequence = get_sequence(random_sample, generator_type)

            X.append(sequence)
            y.append(labels[random_sample])

        yield np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

**What I expected:**

Given that now the model should be able to generalize a bit better, due to ensuring that all the samples are seen at training with an equal frequency, I expected that the test accuracy would increase slightly.

**What happened:**

I ran 3 training sessions on this model (same train/valid/test partitioning) and the test accuracy mean this time was 96.2%. That is a 0.7% decrease in accuracy from the 1st setup. So it seems that the model now generalizes worse.

**Losses plots for each run:**

[image: Losses plot]

**Question:**

Why does more randomness in `frame_generator()` result in better test set accuracy?
Seems rather counterintuitive to me.

Comment: Do you also train the 1st method 3 times to get the mean of test acc?

Comment: @Mr_U4913 Yes, I do. I wrote the following about the 1st method: _This works well, I ran 3 training sessions on this model (same setup, same train/valid/test partitioning) and the test accuracy mean was 96.9%._

Comment: is it possible to take a look at your loss plot?

Comment: @Mr_U4913 Yes, it is. Just added to the question the losses plots for each run. Do you get any insight from the plots? I do not.

Comment: Hi, Alex. From the plots, the training loss is higher than the validation loss so that I suspect that the model is underfitting. Generally, using the 2nd method produces a wide gap between training loss and validation loss. I doubt that training and validation are not appropriately separated. It is possible that you training set have many hard cases to learn or validation and test set have many 'easy` examples. I am not sure why the randomness will improve the performance.

Comment: @Mr_U4913 Hmm, I understand. Thank you for sharing your view on it!

Comment: Did you figure it out ?

Comment: @Mr_U4913 I wouldn't say that I figured it out, but I believe the 2nd method should be the one to be used. Seems like the ImageDataGenerator() from Keras uses the same idea (as method 2) of shuffling the samples before each epoch (so same frequency) and then using them for training. Moreover, the random seed is not fixed to the same value for these experiments, which could influence the results, some might be 'luckier' than others. Unfortunately, won't have more time to look into this and will just role with 2nd method.